# How can I get the counter to work in this code?

Tags: java, counter

I want to count the attempts a user needed to guess the right number, how can I get the counter, which is "i" in this case, to work? I've implemented it in the ationPerformed, but then it will only count one go through even though the button is pressed multible times. How can I fix this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class Zahlenraten{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Zahlenraten");
        f.setSize(500,500);
        //f.setLayout(null);
        
        JTextField t = new JTextField("");
        t.setBounds(95,10,150,30);
        f.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                t.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        
        
        JButton e = new JButton("Exit");
        e.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        e.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 30);
        
        JLabel txt = new JLabel("Zahl eingeben:");
        txt.setBounds(10,10,150,30);
        
        Random r = new Random();
        int Zahl = r.nextInt(100-0+1);
        
        int i = 0;
        
        JButton b = new JButton("Prüfen");
        f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);//Enter Key = button b
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
                
                i++;
                    
                String str = t.getText();
                int wert = Integer.parseInt(str);
                t.setText("");
                
                if(wert < Zahl) {
                    System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert ist größer.");
                }
                if(wert > Zahl) {
                    System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert ist kleiner.");
                }
                if(wert == Zahl) {
                    System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert wurde gefunden!");
                }
            }
        });
        b.setBounds(10,100,100,30);
    
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(null);
        p.add(b);
        p.add(e);
        p.add(t);
        p.add(txt);
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: make it a static class variable of your class Zahlenraten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below solution

```
import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.util.Random;
    
    public class Zahlenraten{
        static int i = 0;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Zahlenraten");
            f.setSize(500,500);
            //f.setLayout(null);
            
            JTextField t = new JTextField("");
            t.setBounds(95,10,150,30);
            f.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
             
                public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                    t.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
            
            
            JButton e = new JButton("Exit");
            e.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            e.setBounds(300, 100, 100, 30);
            
            JLabel txt = new JLabel("Zahl eingeben:");
            txt.setBounds(10,10,150,30);
            
            Random r = new Random();
            int Zahl = r.nextInt(100-0+1);
            
            
            
            JButton b = new JButton("Prüfen");
            f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);//Enter Key = button b
            b.addActionListener(evt -> {
                 i++;
                 
                 String str = t.getText();
                 int wert = Integer.parseInt(str);
                 t.setText("");
                 
                 if(wert!=Zahl) {
                     System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert ist kleiner.");
                 }
                 if(wert == Zahl) {
                     System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert wurde gefunden!");
                 }
            });
            b.setBounds(10,100,100,30);
        
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(null);
            p.add(b);
            p.add(e);
            p.add(t);
            p.add(txt);
            f.add(p);
            f.setVisible(true);
            
        }
    }
```

and the output is [image]

Comment: I've declared i as static like this: "static int i = 0;". But then I get the error: "Illegal modifier for parameter i; only final is permitted". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Interface like:

```
Interface Counter{
      public static int count = 0;
}
```

And then invoke the property of Counter Interface

```
            b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
                
                Copunter.count++;
                    
                String str = t.getText();
                int wert = Integer.parseInt(str);
                t.setText("");
                
                if(wert  Zahl) {
                    System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert ist kleiner.");
                }
                if(wert == Zahl) {
                    System.out.println("Der gesuchte Wert wurde gefunden!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I get this error when I insert the Interface: "Multiple markers at this line
 - Interface cannot be resolved to a type
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete "
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where did you insert Interface?? just create a new file as Interface in the same directory and named it Counter.

Comment: I made a new file for the Interface and it worked. At first I've written it in the main file, that was my mistake. Thanks very much!

Comment: It's a best practice, keep it up. BTW, glad to hear that it helped.